# SQL: How do you select only groups that do not contain a certain value?

Tags: sql, group-by

Say I have a table:

```
Restaurant locations: 

RESTAURANT_NO | RESTAURANT_LOCATION
-----------------------------------
1             |            City A
1             |            City B
2             |            City A
2             |            City B
2             |            City C
3             |            City C
4             |            City A
4             |            City B
```

How would I be able to group them together and also only select the 
RESTAURANT_NO that do not have locations in city C?

Using this example, I want to return:

```
 RESTAURANT_NO
 -------------
 1
 4
```

Since RESTAURANT_NO 2 and 3 both have locations in city C.

I do not know how to group RESTAURANT_NO together while also trying only to select the groups that meet this requirement.

EDIT: I got this working.

However, there is one last thing that I still have not been able to figure out.
The following table has the ID number of people along with cities they have worked in:

```
PERSON_NO | CITY_NAME
---------------------
1         |    City A
2         |    City B
3         |    City A
3         |    City B
3         |    City C
4         |    City A
4         |    City B
4         |    City C
```

How would I be able to get the PERSON_NO of all the people
who have lived in all three cities, A,B, and C?

I want to return

```
PERSON_NO
---------
3
4
```

Thanks, again. I haven't had that much experience with SQL and so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

One way:

```
SELECT RESTAURANT_NO FROM restaurant WHERE RESTAURANT_NO NOT IN
(SELECT RESTAURANT_NO FROM restaurant WHERE RESTAURANT_LOCATION = 'City C')
```

Comment: I've tested my DB with this query and it seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: I've tested in my Database with above query,it is working fine,Thank you

Comment: In case you're using this (good!) answer for your own purposes, remember that you will get no results at all if the subquery returns NULL, i.e. RESTAURANT_NO in this case). It's never NULL in this particular example, but for the more generic use you might want to insert an IS NOT NULL check. :-)

Comment: @Jonas how would you incorporate IS NOT NULL check in the above statement?

Comment: @AlGuy I know you didn't ask me, but here's a way: `SELECT RESTAURANT_NO FROM restaurant WHERE (RESTAURANT_NO NOT IN
(SELECT RESTAURANT_NO FROM restaurant WHERE RESTAURANT_LOCATION = 'City C') OR (RESTAURANT_NO IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM restaurant WHERE RESTAURANT_NO IS NULL AND RESTAURANT_LOCATION = 'City C'))`

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      Restaurant_no
FROM 
      TableX t
WHERE 
      NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM TableX c
        WHERE c.Restaurant_no = t.Restaurant_no
          AND c.Restaurant_location = 'City C'
      )
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `DISTINCT`.

try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.Restaurant_No
FROM Restaurant t
WHERE t.Restaurant_No NOT IN
       (SELECT s.Restaurant_No  
        FROM  Restaurant s
        WHERE s.RESTAURANT_LOCATION = 'City C')
ORDER BY t.Restaurant_No
```