# Select Rows which does not satisfiy Predicate in SQL Server

Tags: sql

I have a table with 2 columns GroupID and Value. Column GroupID have two groups 1 and 2 and its respective values. I have to select GroupID which 
do not have Value 4

```
GroupID Value
1            4
1            5
1            6
1            7
1            8
2            5
2            7
2            8
2            9
2            3

OutPut:

GroupID   Value
2         5
2         7
2         8
2         9
2         3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: How do you select only groups that do not contain a certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355241/sql-how-do-you-select-only-groups-that-do-not-contain-a-certain-value)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `not exists`

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM T t1
WHERE not exists (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM T tt
    where tt.Value = 4 and tt.GroupID = t1.GroupID
)
```

another way you can use *window function* with `count`

```
select * from (
    SELECT t1.*,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN Value = 4 THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY GroupID) cnt
    FROM T t1
) t1
where cnt = 0
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=45ed7f2e734972d2c2c1fb6b42971cc1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NOT IN`

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE GroupID NOT IN (SELECT GroupID FROM YourTable WHERE Value = 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select t.* 
from table t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table t1 
                  where t1.GroupID = t.GroupID and t1.value = 4
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of having clause,

The HAVING clause sets conditions on the GROUP BY clause similar to the way that WHERE interacts with SELECT.

For your case the query would be-

```
Select groupID, value from tablename group by groupID having value !=4
```